# How to Split and save to array

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, split

```
^0806EA^0406F0^^^^^^EF07F7--^E3DC03--^EAFE02--
^0406F0^^^FFE209^^^DFF107^^^F6F508^^^E4DE01^^^EF07F7--^E803E6--
```

in the above code, i want to split this ^ but the problem is, this hex data have same pattern ^.

I want the result like this :

```
^0806EA ^0406F0^^^^^ ^EF07F7-- ^E3DC03-- ^EAFE02--
^0406F0^^ ^FFE209^^ ^DFF107^^ ^F6F508^^ ^E4DE01^^ ^EF07F7-- ^E803E6--
```

or :

```
0806EA 0406F0^^^^^ EF07F7-- E3DC03-- EAFE02--
0406F0^^ FFE209^^ DFF107^^ F6F508^^ E4DE01^^ EF07F7-- E803E6--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want any characters used up in the split--and you also don't seem to want them as a group themselves, you need what is called "zero-width assertion". Since we're talking about carets, word boundaries aren't going to work. It's not at the beginning or end of a line, and so the only ZWA that is going to work is a lookahead or a lookbehind.

Since you want to break your chunks *in front* of specified pattern, I would suggest a lookahead, consisting of: a caret + a non-caret OR end of string, like so:

```
split /(?=\^(?:[^^]|$))/;
```

Illustrated below:

```
while ( <DATA> ) { 
    my @list = split /(?=\^(?:[^^]|$))/;
    say "@list";
}

__DATA__
^0806EA^0406F0^^^^^^EF07F7--^E3DC03--^EAFE02--
^0406F0^^^FFE209^^^DFF107^^^F6F508^^^E4DE01^^^EF07F7--^E803E6--
```

Outputs:

```
^0806EA ^0406F0^^^^^ ^EF07F7-- ^E3DC03-- ^EAFE02--

^0406F0^^ ^FFE209^^ ^DFF107^^ ^F6F508^^ ^E4DE01^^ ^EF07F7-- ^E803E6--
```

Comment: i test your code with the data i have and the result like what i want.
Perfect....Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=.)(?=\^\w)/ /g' infile
```

Explanation:

```
s/regex/replacement       # Substitution command.
(?<=.)                    # Positive look-behind for any char.
(?=\^\w)                  # Positive look-ahead for '^' plus a word character.
                          # Add a space between them.
```

Result:

```
^0806EA ^0406F0^^^^^ ^EF07F7-- ^E3DC03-- ^EAFE02--
^0406F0^^ ^FFE209^^ ^DFF107^^ ^F6F508^^ ^E4DE01^^ ^EF07F7-- ^E803E6--
```